# Is there a reason #, ##, ### tags are bold instead of just larger fonts?

Tags: feature-request

Reasoning:
I want to make an easily visually parse-able answer.  I can add bold tags if I need them, but I can't remove them if I don't.

Should the heading markdown really be bold or just larger fonts?  If I can make h1,2,3 that are larger text and add bold as desired, I might not get complaints about answers like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9914722#9914722).

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308774/is-there-a-way-to-gain-superuser-access-from-a-qt-app/308800#308800) the example answer that might be easier to read without bold, but with larger fonts.  It would let users easily break down the answer in sections, but not be yelling at them on the bold end of things.

Comment: In my experience, headers/titles are typeset in bold, so that markdown does it too is consistent. Non-bold large fonts tend to look ugly, by the way.

Comment: @DanielFischer - that's a fair point.

Comment: I'm comfortable with a "Nope.  Daniel has it right" answer.  I just thought that maybe it should be asked somewhere and have a reason given.

Comment: `#+` is used for headlines, so it makes sense for them to be bold - the lack of a simple font-size manipulation markdown is the problem here, though.

Comment: @FEichinger - I agree, and that's a fair point.  I'm trying to find a way to fix it.

Comment: That answer is so short I don't really know why you think you need loads of headings and italics anyway. Even if they weren't bold it just disrupts the flow.

Comment: My eyes! Too much... styling...

Comment: @MartinSmith The italics were to make it not bold, if I remember what I was trying to do.